# How to return the input from prototype if false

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to return the string that called the function.

But it doesn't return the string… it returns an array.

```js
String.prototype.testing = function testing() {
  if (this === "what") {}
  return this //Should return - this is a string
}


x = "this is a string"

y = x.testing()

console.log(y)
```

Comment: Where it is defined that `this` is a string ?

Comment: x is the one calling the function… so isn't this considered x?

Comment: and x is "this is a string"

Comment: It works for me, I get "this is a string" on the console

Comment: Why does the snippet include jQuery? There's no jQuery used...

Comment: Exactly, this has nothing to do with jQuery

Comment: Sorry about tha't… I started off with jQuery and couldn't get the prototype to work for some reason. Then just reverted back to javascript

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JavaScript has both `String` objects and string primitives. In a `String.prototype` method in loose mode, `this` is a string **object**. (In strict mode, it's whatever the method was called on, which is frequently a string primitive.) What you're seeing from `console.log` isn't an array, it's just how that particular `console` implementation outputs a `String` object rather than string primitive:

```js
console.log(new String("hi"));
```

There is a bug in the code, though: `this === "what"` will never be true in loose mode, because `"what"` is a string primitive, but `this` is a `String` object, and `===` isn't allowed to coerce. You'd want `this.toString() === "what"` or `this == "what"`. You'd probably also want to do something in the block attached to the `if`. And if you want to return a string primitive when returning `this`, you might want `return this.toString();` at the end.

E.g., something like:

```js
String.prototype.testing = function testing() {
  if (this == "what") {
    return "it was what";
  }
  return this.toString();
};

var x = "this is a string";
var y = x.testing();
console.log(y);
x = "what";
y = x.testing();
console.log(y);
```

Or using strict mode, something like this:

```js
"use strict";
String.prototype.testing = function testing() {
  if (this == "what") { // Could still be either a primitive or object, depending
    return "it was what";
  }
  return this; // No need for toString here
};

var x = "this is a string";
var y = x.testing();
console.log(y);
x = "what";
y = x.testing();
console.log(y);
```

Comment: @llama: Good catch, I'd had a "doh!" moment a couple of minutes ago and was editing that information in.

Comment: Is it just because the string primitive is immutable & can't have methods added onto it?

Comment: @cygorx: Being immutable doesn't mean you can't have methods. It's because the string primitive is a **primitive**. Primitives don't have methods. They *seem* to because of special treatment by the JavaScript engine: When you call a method on a primitive (or look up any non-intrinsic property on it), the engine promoties the primitive to an object, looks up the property/method, and then (in the case of a method) calls that method with `this` set to the primitive (in strict mode) or the object (in loose mode).

Comment: :o So wait, is it actually wrong to call, say, toString (called on a primitive) a method?

Comment: @cygorx: :-) Well, you could argue that until ES2015, JavaScript didn't have methods ([and I did](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)). But it's fine (in my view) to call `toString` a method even when you call it on a primitive, because the mechanism by which it gets called involves a `String` object (in theory; naturally, implementations optimize it).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That's so interesting holy bananas

Answer (score -1):

You have a ... not a bug but there is no need to add a function name when you assign it, here:

```
String.prototype.testing = function **testing**() {}
```

There is not necessarily something wrong with your code but you are not seeing what you expect :)

Fo example with what you have `x == x.testing()` even if `console.log(x)` looks different than `console.log(x.testing())`.

They are equal but different in type, one is a string object other is a string primitive, as T. J. nicely explained while I was posting :).

```js
    String.prototype.testing = function () {
      if (this === "what") {}
      return this.toString();
    }


    x = "this is a string"

    y = x.testing()

    console.log(y)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: correct answer, but could you pls add an explanation?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder explained very nicely below :)